# Simulating a MIDI device - Windows

Tags: windows, driver, device, midi

I need some advice on windows programming, MIDI and WDM.  I am trying to write a small application that will sit in the sys tray and be advertised to the system as a MIDI In/Out device so that MIDI programs can send to it and it will convert the messages into a different format.  I have been reading Cant's WDM book and scouring for information about writing device drivers, but don't know if I'm going down the right path.
  I don't see yet how to:-

a) register my driver as MIDI capable (do I stick a ref to it in the registery and let the OS direct MIDI calls to the functionality in a dll?)

b) direct MIDI data through the my driver to my app, which is probably going to be too large to be a driver itself.

Any advice on where to start would be much appreciated.
thanks,
Pete

Answer (score 8):

Windows MIDI drivers do not need to be implemented in the kernel, they can be implemented entirely in userspace as DLLs.

MSDN has some information about the functions you need to implement - 
[Audio Device Messages for MIDI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff536194(v=VS.85).aspx) - unfortunately it is somewhat lacking.

There used to be sample code for this kind of driver, as part of the NT4 DDK, but more recent releases of the DDK / WDK unfortunately don't include it any more.

Some better (though older) documentation and sample code can still be found after some searching:

- [Introduction to Multimedia Drivers](http://mediaxw.sourceforge.net/files/tmp/Windows%20NT%20DDK%20-%20Multimedia%20Drivers.pdf) (From NT4 DDK)
- [Sample MIDI Wine Driver for Mac OS X](http://source.winehq.org/source/dlls/winecoreaudio.drv/midi.c)

Answer (score 2):

Devices are enumerated (or simulated) by device drivers, not applications. What you see in the sys tray is an application icon. Hence, you will need to have both a driver and an app - you can't have one bit of compiled code acting as both.

On the driver side, you probably want to have a peek at [the MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff537519.aspx). This will answer part (a) of yopur question.

Assuming that you still would like to continue, (b) is best don by letting your application pull the data from the driver. That's far easier than the other way around - an application can trivially find a driver, but a driver has big problems finding a specific app (process)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've been reading more of the drivers book and running the samples this afternoon and I am starting to see a path through this.  One thing?  Having my app continously perform a read to pull info from the device driver seems inefficient.  Is there no easy way to register my app with the driver to be given a nudge via some form of IPC to wake up and pull the data?
Things are becoming more clear ... slowly.
cheers,
Pete

Comment: Just use a cyclic buffer in your driver. MIDI is fairly realtime; if there's no application consuming it, the driver can safely overwrite older data.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a bit easier way to get started, there is a MIDI loopback driver out there, and the folks that make it also offer (or used to offer) a version of it that allows your program to communicate directly with the driver.  This gives you the behavior you are looking for, where a program appears as a MIDI device.  The loopback driver is at http://nerds.de/en/loopbe1.html.  I don't see the developer page anymore, but if you contact them, you might be able to purchase a license to a driver that you can access directly without the loopback.

Comment: Unfortunately, these are heavily license-encumbed and cannot be used to learn from or even extend for your own implementations.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Of course... that's the cost of someone else doing the work.  In any case, e-mail Tobias Erichsen.  https://www.tobias-erichsen.de/software/loopmidi.html  His driver has a nice API for setting up ports named whatever you'd like, in various configurations.

Comment: I know it does, already did, but given that his driver is the only one, as an open source developer that's "great for my own audio work, but not good enough for the open source programming I need to do" =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Fair enough, but unfortunately I think that's reality in this case.  Unless of course you know of an open source implementation... and that would be great to see.

Comment: it would be, which is how I got here. I'm googling for information on how to implement a win10 virtual midi device and driver so I can stop relying on loopbe1 and have code that can be community maintained past what I specifically need it for.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Please update us as you  make progress!  That's exciting.